# How to prove that the likelihood of a proportional hazards with lognormal baseline model is log concave?

Tags: survival, likelihood, proportional-hazards, concavity

I want to fit a survival model using a [proportional hazards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_hazards_model) assumption

$$h(t) = h_0(t)\exp(x^T\beta),$$

where 
$$h_0(t) = \dfrac{\frac{1}{\sigma t} \phi \left(\frac{\log(t) - \mu}{\sigma}\right)}{\Phi \left(-\frac{\log(t) - \mu}{\sigma}\right)},$$
is the baseline hazard associated to the [lognormal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution). The likelihood function is:

$$L(\beta,\mu,\sigma) = \prod_{i=1}^n  h(t_i)^{d_i}\exp\left(-H(t_i)\right) ,$$

The corresponding log-likelihood function associated to a sample $t_1,\dots,t_n$ with censoring indicators $d_1,\dots,d_n$ is

$$l(\beta,\mu,\sigma) = \sum_{i=1}^n d_i \log h_0(t_i) + \sum_{i=1}^n d_i x_i^T\beta - \sum_{i=1}^n  H_0(t_i)\exp(x_i^T\beta),$$
where $H_0(t) = - \log\Phi \left(-\frac{\log(t) - \mu}{\sigma}\right)$ is the cumulative hazard function.

**Question**. How can I prove that this log likelihood function is concave?

Comment: Take two derivatives of the log-likelihood and show that it is negatively valued.